How does Go manage multiple versions of dependency?
I have a go application which imports packages A@v1.0.0 and B@v1.0.0 . Meanwhile A@v1.0.0 imports B@v1.1.0, and A@v1.0.0 won't work if A imports B@v1.0.0 .
Will my application compile successfully? Which version of package B is eventually used, v1.0.0 or v1.1.0 or both? Do I have to update my application's dependency of package B to v1.1.0, the newest version?

use golang modules ... in your top most directory create your go.mod file by issuing ...  go mod init   ...  if you do not have circular dependencies and your code compiles go will resolve the versions  ...  experiment to discover ... if actual packages in question are too complex I suggest you create a toy project where you can control your above mentioned setup and play about ... software is all about discovery and experimentation

Almost any project with a significant number of dependencies will have to resolve transitive versions which differ slightly between the dependencies. This is perfectly normal. Read the docs here to understand minimum version selection, and try building your project to see what actually happens.

Assuming you are using modules...
(some of this may also apply if the packages are versioned differently, e.g. major version folders, but I have only ever worked with go modules and cannot be certain of any substantive differences in other approaches, if any)
Major Version Differences
Golang includes the major version slug in a module's identity if these packages are in modules, which provides unique identities for packages in different major versions of the same module (except v0/v1), allowing them to co-exist.  Multiple versions can even be imported into the same package, with aliasing used to differentiate as required:
import (
    bar1 "github.com/foo/B/bar"
    bar2 "github.com/foo/B/v2/bar"
)

As is mentioned in the docs quite frequently (see links below), a new major version of a module is effectively an entirely new and separate module.
i.e. in the scenario you describe, your project should compile just fine.
However, it may not behave as expected if module B has implementation details that assume a single major version in an application.
e.g. if a package in B implements an init() function, this will be called twice, rather than the one time that the code in module B may require or expect.  Similarly, any package level variables in B will have separate v1 and v2 values, so if B assumes these are singletons, it may behave unexpectedly.
If these issues do arise, they are arguably a problem with the design of B, but if that module is not under your control, it may become your problem to deal with.
More information on module versioning may be gleaned from the official docs here and here.
Minor/Patch Version Differences
What Version Is Used?
If A v1.0.0 imports B v1.1.0 and APP imports A v1.0.0 and B v1.0.0 then APP will use B v1.1.0.
go mod tidy will automatically update the dependencies actually used to compile APP (go.sum), but it is up to you to update the stated APP dependency in the APP go.mod file.  Whether you do that to address dependency "hygiene" or wait until APP explicitly depends on B v1.1.0 is largely up to you and your team's practices.
Will It Compile?
Your project should compile in this situation, but whether it does or not is somewhat out of the hands of the Golang dependency management mechanisms.  It is contingent on the author(s) of modules A and B having correctly applied semantic versioning.
i.e. B v1.1.0 should only introduce new features compared to v1.0.0.  A v1.0.0 may use those features while APP uses only features from B v1.0.0, which should still be present in B v1.1.0, meaning that APP should also compile against B v1.1.0 despite being explicitly dependent on v1.0.0.
But if B v1.1.0 incorrectly (or inadvertently, or perhaps even deliberately) introduces a breaking change when compared to v1.0.0 the APP project may not compile if it relies on something that has changed.

Thank you for your answer. I did not express my question clearly, and I updated my question. Would you please answer again?
